# Bootstrap modal showing grayed at top of page. Cannot click on modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

Having issues with my modal implementation with Javascript/JQuery/HTML. Not really sure what I'm missing as far as CSS properties to make this work. Below you'll see snippets of my code/images of the issue

Here is the code snippets for my modal.

---APPENDS----

````
```                 //MODAL START
.append($(`<div>`)
.attr(`id`,`myModal`)
.addClass(`modal custom`)
.attr(`role`,`dialog`)
.css(`display`,`none`)
.css(`background-color`, `rgba(0,0,0,0)`)
//MODAL DIALOG START
.append($(`<div>`)
  .attr(`class`,`dialog`)
  //MODAL CONTENT START
  .append($(`<div>`)
    .attr(`class`,`modal-content`)
  //MODAL HEADER START
    .append($(`<div>`)
      .attr(`class`,`modal-header`)
      //MODAL HEADER BUTTON START
      .append($(`<button>`)
        .attr(`type`,`button`)
        .attr(`id`,`modal-header-btn-x`)
        .addClass(`close`)
        .attr(`data-dismiss`,`modal`)
        .text(`X`)
      )//MODAL HEADER BUTTON END
      .append($(`<h4>`)
        .attr(`class`,`modal-title`)
      )
    )//MODAL HEADER END

  //MODAL CONTENT BODY START
    .append($(`<div>`)
      .attr(`id`,`tweet-modal-body`)
      .attr(`class`,`modal-body`)
    )
    //MODAL CONTENT BODY END
    //MODAL FOOTER START
    .append($(`<div>`)
      .attr(`class`,`modal-footer`)
      .append($(`<button>`)
        .attr(`id`,`modal-footer-btn-x`)
        .attr(`type`,`button`)
        .attr(`class`,`btn btn-default`)
        .attr(`data-dismiss`,`modal`)
        .text(`X`)
      )
    ) //MODAL FOOTER END
   
  )//MODAL CONTENT END

)//MODAL DIALOG END
````

-----CSS-----

```
.myModal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
     /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1020; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    
  }
  body.modal{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal{
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

---JAVASCRIPT---

```
$(`#tweet-box`).on('click',`.user`,function(){ $(`#myModal`).modal('show'); //modal.style.display = "block";})
```

After click:
[image: after click]

Before click:
[image: before click]

Comment: This is an odd way to approach this issue. Did you read the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ ? It seems like you are generating the modal in a over complicated way.

Comment: I did as much as I could. I think i figured a different way to just show the user's timeline in the parent element now instead of Modals. 

I don't know enough about them to really dive deep. (learning JS for the first time)